# how do you assign a non-generic Map to a generic Map in flow type

Tags: flowtype

I'm trying to assign a non-generic map to a generic map, but flow complains that the value is incompatible. Is there anyway around this. Look at `m4` and `m5` in the example below.

```
interface Person  {
 name: string;
}

type Doctor =  {
  name: string,
  license: string,
}

var d:Doctor = {
  name: 'Sam',
  license: 'PHD'
};
var p: Person = d;

// It is possible to create a generic array where each element 
// implements the interface Person
const a: Array<Person> = [d];

// As a Map, it appears you cannot the value cannot be generic array
let m2: Map<string, Array<Doctor>> = new Map<string, Array<Doctor>> ();
let m3: Map<string, Array<Person>> = m2;


// As a Map, it appears that value cannot be a generic object 
let m4: Map<string, Doctor> = new Map<string, Doctor> ();
m4.set('bob', d);
let m5: Map<string, Person> = m4;
```

It errors with the following statement

```
28: let m5: Map<string, Person> = m4;
                                  ^ Cannot assign `m4` to `m5` because property `license` is missing in `Person` [1] but exists in `Doctor` [2] in type argument `V` [3]. [prop-missing]
```

[Flow](https://flow.org/try/#0JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgArQM4HsTOQbwChkQ4BbCALmQzClAHMBuQgX0MLAE8AHFAESwIwWKMgC8eInlIVqteiAYAaYsgA2wJCAxUadRqvaEAbnDEATSoOGiJBNbL0ByAMrlnqvJu27qz1AAJfmc2FjMxHmp0KGxcSQsWQgB6ZOQASTBkYAxkHiwMDGAAI3UUEWQEKAg4SGQ4ZAYIEGgteqgoOC5kAHcAC2gUGoQ+5AgyinBkFLTgMh4J5rBcsAHs8Gh4JDRMHEIEHFp66gBBDq6AHhi4gD57AG0LAF0k1OQT3IaAWTgeZWysr8+OZclwsABXSpwEAgLBZVYoMzqcEoBDQ2FZYooJotegIdqdLiEMpZMgAJmoPx4FwUhne5y4FxsIigNzukhaPWQVJpBiU-zOhKZQhZbOQAAoAJQsEnIMgAZkpv15ihU9KF1xwYsk5KSM3en25v3+wEBPGBsWQq1qyCRKKhMLhyCx9UazVa+KwxQAVhBhNNZWQACxK6m0-nIZmidkkCBcnnhtVR1kS6WEYMAOl0YHFzmKXs8yAsacDAFZQyq6ZqQDHg0wgA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is failing because it would be valid to do

```
m5.set("foo", { name: "foo" });
```

since that is a valid `Person` and that would corrupt `m4` since it no longer contains `Doctor` objects.

For your code to work, you `m5` needs to be read-only, and `m3` needs to be read-only with read-only arrays, e.g.

```
let m3: $ReadOnlyMap<string, $ReadOnlyArray<Person>> = m2;
```

and

```
let m5: $ReadOnlyMap<string, Person> = m4;
```

([Flow Try](https://flow.org/try/#0JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgArQM4HsTOQbwChkQ4BbCALmQzClAHMBuQgX0MLAE8AHFAESwIwWKMgC8eInlIVqteiAYAaYsgA2wJCAxUadRqvaEAbnDEATSoOGiJBNbL0ByAMrlnqvJu27qz1AAJfmc2FjMxHmp0KGxcSQsWQgB6ZOQASTBkYAxkHiwMDGAAI3UUEWQEKAg4SGQ4ZAYIEGgteqgoOC5kAHcAC2gUGoQ+5AgyinBkFLTgMh4J5rBcsAHs8Gh4JDRMHEIEHFp66gBBDq6AHhi4gD57AG0LAF0k1OQT3IaAWTgeZWysr8+OZclwsABXSpwEAgLBZVYoMzqcEoBDQ2FZYooJotegIdqdLiEMpZMgAJmoPx4FwUhne5y4FxsIigNzukhaPWQVJpBiU-zOhKZQhZbOQAAoAJQsEnIMgAZmoABIAEo1CwAeRA6i4PNp-OQqvVWp1gsu1xwYsk5KSM3en25v3+wEBPGBsWQq1qyCRKKhMLhyCx9UazVa+KwxQAVhBhNNZWQACyU368xQqZDM0TskgQLl6vkZrOsiXSwhJgB0ujA4ucxUjnmQFjLCYArMq1XBNdrdan9RmLSAc0mmEA))

Comment: Thanks for explanation. I read here that $ReadOnlyMap is not documented in the official docs: https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/7705 Do you know if it would be safe to use in production? The last thing I want is for the  $ReadOnlyMap type to be deprecated.

Comment: It's pretty critical for code like what you're writing here so I can't imagine that they'd remove it.